# Error When running Windows Azure for PHP samples

Tags: php, rest, azure

With reference to example at http://cloudstory.in/2012/02/windows-azure-storage-for-php-developers/ Why does require_once 'Microsoft/WindowsAzure/Storage/Blob.php'; give an error saying Unable to access Microsoft/WindowsAzure/Storage/Blob.php. But if I try to locate Blob.php in the folder structure it is located at pear\WindowsAzure\Blob\Models\Blob.php. If I change this path to the correct one I get this error  Class 'Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob' not found.

Comment: Please can someone help fix the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the new official Microsoft Windows Azure PHP package? Following the tutorial from this http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/ , it should work!

Comment: Yes I followed exactly the same steps mentioned here.

Comment: The tutorial you mentioned above is outdated, you should use the official one http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/blob-service/